# Image upload in magento not working properly

Tags: image

I am working on image upload by custom module. In this module if I upload image named

> Screenshot (1).jpg

When file get upload it saved with name

> Screenshot_1_.jpg

Because of this image didnt get showed on website. Below is code for uploading image.

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {
            try {   
                /* Starting upload */
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');

                // Any extention would work
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                // Set the file upload mode 
                // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                // true -> get the file in the product like folders 
                //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                // We set media as the upload dir
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media')."/home/sectionzero/" ;
                $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name'] );

            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }

            //this way the name is saved in DB
            $data['filename']['value'] = "home/sectionzero/".$_FILES['filename']['name'];
        }
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behaviour of the uploader. Files should not have spaces in the name. You should save the filename after the upload and not before since the file's name before and after uploading will differ.